# Writing a Firefox Extension that uses XPCOM components?

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm trying to write a Firefox extension that writes Firefox's history into the Windows system history, which ought to be useful for folks at work who use IE *and* Firefox to get work done.

Adding pages to IE history appears simple enough ([IUrlHistoryStg::AddUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767717(VS.85).aspx) ought to do it). However, my experience with Firefox extensions is limited to small chrome hacks packaged together in an XPI.

From my initial reading, it appears that I have to create a XPCOM component that will insert URLs into history. I'm not sure this can be done using Javascript, and I don't have much experience in writing extensions that use XPCOM components.

Could anyone familiar with Firefox extension development please point to any tutorials about writing extensions that use XPCOM components, especially those written using C++? Or are there any open-source extensions that use components I could look at to learn more about this?

Comment: The best you can do is start from [this book](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_XPCOM_Components).